# query based on previous lines values: values that open the 30 days windows (and are not inside them)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, relational-database

I have a service in which customers can open a "customer service ticket" which is charged. Whenever they do, they can open how many more "customer service tickets" they want for the next 30 days without being charged; and after that period if they open a ticket again they will be charged again (and if that happens, they will have another 30 days of free customer service).

Based on that, I have a table called customer_service_ticket in which I store each ticket with its date on "date" column.

What query gets all tickets which are chargeable, that is, these tickets that open the 30 days windows (and not tickets inside them)?

Eg. If the tickets have the dates
3/jan - 4/jan - 8/jan - 30/jan - 4/fev - 20/fev - 20/mar

the query should only return
3/jan - 4/fev - 20/mar.

Because every statement is applied to all lines, I couldn't find a solution. I am working on a recursive CTE.

Comment: Please include relevant table DDL as inline, formatted text when posting a question. From the description, it appears that the only way to determine charged tickets is by assuming that the first ticket is charged and then stepping through the remaining tickets to determine which others would start 30 day windows. Is there no mechanism to determine which were charged tickets without examing all of the tickets? If not, that would seem to be a serious design flaw. At the very least, there should be either a flag on the tickets table or an associated charges table to identify charged tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE is required for this type of problem because the selected rows are dependent on prior selected rows.

The following demonstrates a query that performs the requested operation:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  tickets(ticket_id, customer_id, ticket_date) AS (
    VALUES (1, 1, '2023-01-03'::date),
           (2, 1, '2023-01-04'::date),
           (3, 1, '2023-01-30'::date),
           (4, 1, '2023-02-04'::date),
           (5, 1, '2023-02-20'::date),
           (6, 1, '2023-03-20'::date)
  ),
  parms AS (
    SELECT 30 AS support_days
  ),
  charged_tickets AS (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.customer_id) t.customer_id,
                          t.ticket_id,
                          t.ticket_date,
                          t.ticket_date + p.support_days AS next_chargeable_start
                     FROM parms p
                     CROSS JOIN tickets t
                     ORDER BY t.customer_id, t.ticket_date, t.ticket_id) first_charged_tickets
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.customer_id) t.customer_id,
                          t.ticket_id,
                          t.ticket_date,
                          t.ticket_date + p.support_days AS next_chargeable_start
                     FROM parms p
                     CROSS JOIN tickets t
                     JOIN charged_tickets
                       ON t.customer_id = charged_tickets.customer_id
                         AND t.ticket_date >= charged_tickets.next_chargeable_start
                     ORDER BY t.customer_id, t.ticket_date, t.ticket_id) next_charged_tickets
  )
SELECT ct.customer_id, ct.ticket_id, ct.ticket_date
  FROM charged_tickets ct
  ORDER BY ct.customer_id, ct.ticket_date;
```

Results:

| customer_id | ticket_id | ticket_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-03 |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-02-04 |
| 1 | 6 | 2023-03-20 |

The query begins by establishing example data as `tickets` (this would be an actual table for production use). The number of support days is defined in `parms`. This allows the query to be more DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself).

The recursive CTE is found in `charged_tickets`. The initialization section determines the first charged ticket for each customer and the date after which charges will again apply. The iterative part performs the same operation for each successive charged ticket. The subqueries (`first_charged_tickets` and `next_charged_tickets`) in `charged_tickets` are necessary because PostgreSQL doesn't support `DISTINCT ON` directly in recursive subqueries.

For large datasets, an index, such as the following, can have a significant influence on performance:

```
CREATE INDEX tickets_by_customer_id_and_date
  ON tickets(customer_id, ticket_date) INCLUDE (ticket_id);
```

Such an index, coupled with putting customer selection criteria in the recursive CTE's initialization subquery (i.e., `first_charged_tickets`), can also significantly improve performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This worked just fine for me, elegant solution. Really apreciate it, still learning SQL and this was really helpful